# Unity C# - If statement does not return anything, but debug log does?

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine, timer

My timer is rounded to one decimal. In my update function I check if the timer is 0.8, but when it is 0.8 it does not return anything. However the debug log tells me that it has past 0.8.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/48e883e9b6eda385fb1afe9727b22828.png]

```
void Update() 
{
 Debug.Log ("Elapsed time: " + (Mathf.Round(timerScript.elapsedTime * 10f) / 10f));
 if (((Mathf.Round(timerScript.elapsedTime * 10f) / 10f) == 0.8f)) {
 {
     Debug.Log ("CHECK");
 }
}
```

Is the if statement too slow? How do I fix this?

Comment: You can use `Mathf.Approximately((Mathf.Round(timerScript.elapsedTime * 10f) / 10f), 0.8f)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works :)

Comment: Not a problem at all, apologies for some community members not being helpful at all. The linked answer is not the general way it's done in Unity3d

Comment: Ah, that is the reason why I did not understand what they were doing. Thanks ;)

Comment: @ParadoxForge Next time, just ping me and I can fix it. Now there is a second (and a third) duplicate specific for Unity.